# C - Format char array like printf

Tags: c, string-formatting

I want to format a c string like `printf` does. For example:

```
char string[] = "Your Number:%i";
int number = 33;
// String should now be "Your Number:33"
```

Is there any library or a good way I could do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`sprintf(char* out, const char* format, ... );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) like so:

```
int main() {
  char str[] = "Your Number:%d";
  char str2[1000];
  int number = 33;
  sprintf(str2,str,number);
  printf("%s\n",str2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\temp.exe
Your Number:33

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

Comment: What if you called sprintf() with a 1001 character long string? (answer: a nice segfault. Use snprintf() instead.)

Comment: Thank you, I already thought I remembered that there exists such an function but couldn't remember how it was called.

Comment: @H2C03 - Hmmm, I don't seem to have that function available with my compiler (MS Visual Studio 2008 C++). Good idea though, but I'm not sure it's available on all compilers.

Answer (score 1):

sprintf -  http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Answer (score 0):

For debugging my Arduino sketches, I habitually use this solution, taken from [Madivad](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/304/madivad)'s answer to [How do I print multiple variables in a string?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-do-i-print-multiple-variables-in-a-string).

You add this function to your sketch, that will allow you to use `printf()`, although it falls over for `float`, `%f`.

```
// Function that printf and related will use to print
int serial_putchar(char c, FILE* f) {
    if (c == '\n') serial_putchar('\r', f);
    return Serial.write(c) == 1? 0 : 1;
}
```

Add the global

```
FILE serial_stdout;
```

and put this is `setup()`

```
fdev_setup_stream(&serial_stdout, serial_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
stdout = &serial_stdout;
```

An example sketch would be:

```
// Function that printf and related will use to print
int serial_putchar(char c, FILE* f) {
    if (c == '\n') serial_putchar('\r', f);
    return Serial.write(c) == 1? 0 : 1;
}

FILE serial_stdout;


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Set up stdout
    fdev_setup_stream(&serial_stdout, serial_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
    stdout = &serial_stdout;

    printf("My favorite number is %6d!\n", 12);
}

void loop() {
  static long counter = 0;
  if (millis()%300==0){
    printf("millis(): %ld\tcounter: %ld (%02X)\n", millis(), counter, counter++);
    delay(1);    
  }
}
```